Book about a teen girl who had to move to a country house for the summer but discovered lots of secrets there
It was about a teenage girl who moved to a country house for the summer against her decision. She discovered lots of secrets and locked doors in this house and developed a crush on a boy who was working for the house possibly in the stable!
I remember it was an A5 size and mine was hardback! I used to read it around the time of 2010-2014 I think. I also believe it was based in England but I’m not sure! I was very young but I loved the book I used to reread it all the time.

Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. (1) Could you add a few more details to the description? You can use identification request wiki as a guide.  (2) You used the tag [short-stories] but you description seems to be about a novel. Could you please clarify this?
